# updatefile in application folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsstring

```
NSString *conent = @"One\nnghTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive";
//save content to the documents directory
[conent writeToFile:fileName 
          atomically:NO 
            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy 
               error:nil];
```

here is the code to write data in to file

i want to update that file i have 2000 lines to write as application is used.

Thanks for help.

Comment: how to update that file

once i write 1000 line in that file

After some i want to add more data how to add text if i am doing the same its going to replace the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the NSFileHandle class then writeData, the writing takes place at the file pointer’s current position so use seekToEndOfFile to move the pointer first.

```
NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"One\nnghTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive"]
[fh seekToEndOfFile];
[fh writeData:data];
```

Comment: Before you ask, here is how to convert a NSString to NSData:
NSString * theString=@"abcd";
NSData * data=[theString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];